# What would happen if I uninstall python, would my python project still work?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Let's say I created a django project with the help of  `virtualenv` and I named my virtualenv `venv`, If I uninstall python from my system can I still use my project with the help of that `venv`?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Uninstalling Python would entail removing the Python interpreter in that venv, no? So how could it work? I guess it depends on what you mean by "uninstall".

Comment: Can you maybe add what your *intend* is? Why would you want to uninstall python? What is your goal doing this? Answering purely theoretical question give me a feeling of wasting my time here...

Comment: I have created a simple POS but I don't want to install python in client's computer so is there any way like portable python or e.t.c?

Answer (score 1):

No. It would not work.

Python is an "interpreted" language. Python scripts need the Python interpreter to run as well as its "*standard library and other key files*".

Although there is a `python` or `python.exe` executable binary in a Python virtual environment, it is not a self-sufficient standalone Python interpreter. It still needs the original Python interpreter used to create the virtual environment, or actually, if I am not mistaken, it needs access to "*the standard library and other key files*" of the original Python interpreter.

***References***:

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#specification